# Error installing py-bcrypt in Solaris 10

Tags: installation, python, solaris

I'm trying to install Rhodecode into a Solaris 10 server, but when the installer is trying to install bcrypt it fails with the following error:

```
easy_install py-bcrypt
Searching for py-bcrypt
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/py-bcrypt/
Reading http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/
Reading https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/
Reading https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/downloads/list
Reading http://www.mindrot.org/py-bcrypt.html
Best match: py-bcrypt 0.3
Downloading https://py-bcrypt.googlecode.com/files/py-bcrypt-0.3.tar.gz
Processing py-bcrypt-0.3.tar.gz
Running py-bcrypt-0.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-t_OfzJ/py-bcrypt-0.3/egg-dist-tmp-jnXWGe
"bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c", line 29: syntax error before or at: u_int8_t
"bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c", line 29: warning: undefined or missing type for: u_int8_t
"bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c", line 29: warning: function prototype parameters must have types
"bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c", line 86: warning: implicit function declaration: bzero
cc: acomp failed for bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/lib/python2.6/pycc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?, thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103400/how-to-overcome-u-int8-t-vs-uint8-t-issue-efficiently

You'd be safe using the perl solution since you are using a library instead of writing the code that uses this type.

Comment: I solved using the B-K approach, but your link lead me to the solution.
Thanks a lot.